# akka-http: How to extract list of query paramerters

Tags: akka-http

In akka-http, how do we extract a list of query parameters of varying length from incoming request?

Request url can be like this:

```
.../employees?city=london,ny,paris
```

Number of cities may vary with every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your solution, you can replace the `Symbol` part like

```
parameters("city".repeated)
```

See [the akka doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html)

If you want to keep your value as a comma-separated list of values, you can create a custom directive like

```
    def paramAsList(key: String): Directive1[List[String]] =
        parameter(key)
          .map(x => x.split(",").toList)

...

    get {
         paramAsList("city") => cities {
....
```

With this, your url `.../employees?city=london,ny,paris` should work

Answer (score 0):

Got it working as:

```
path("searchByCity") {
        get {
          parameters(Symbol("city").*) {cities =>
            .....
          }
        }
      }
```

URL is now as:

```
.../employees?city=london&city=ny&city=paris
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getQueryParams(url){
   let urlParts = url.split('?');

   if(urlsParts?.length > 1){
    let params = urlParts[1].split('&');
    return params
   }
  return null
}

var queryParams = getQueryParams('.../employees?city=london,ny,paris')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.